# Enable the click of a SharePoint list column

Tags: list-view, custom-list

[image: I have created a cust]om list on SharePoint. The column "Title" which comes by default is hidden in my view as I dont use that column.

I no longer can open the list items as none of the columns are clickable.

How do I enable this? I dont have access to SharePoint designer but have full control on the SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Title column is the only one which can be clicked on to open an item, or appear with its item menu. I approach this by renaming the Title column to one that I actually plan to use, ideally a unique identifier, rather than removing it from view.

Without the Title column (or whatever you have renamed it to) in the view, the user has to open the item by clicking the checkmark and selecting View Item from the ITEMS tab -- far from ideal.

Comment: Just a commentary... it's insane that MS has not added this simple improvement of allowing the "click" column to be selected in the list setup. People have been asking how to do this since SharePoint 2003. It's amazing how stagnant SharePoint has been, all things considered. I I use it everyday so I know.

Comment: Thank you Brendan. I have renamed Title column to one of the columns I was using.

Comment: Glad to hear it, Sachin! And mannaggia, I agree -- but it's a great opportunity for me to start a conversation with my power users about content types :)

Comment: @BrendanW Good job :)  Thank you for your valuable contribution